# How to use/convert best.pt model of YOLOv8s to js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, pytorch, yolov8

I trained a YOLOv8s model on custom dataset in google colab, I have the best.pt file and I want to make the model work on web app using javascript, I saw it can be done using TensorFlow.js but I havn't seen how to do it.

Can someone please refrence me to a source that explain how can I convert it to something that can be run on the browser using javascript. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A YOLOv8 model can be converted to the TF.js format as comes from the official Ultralytics [docs](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/export/?h=export):

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('best.pt')
model.export(format='tfjs', imgsz=640, half=False, int8=False)
```

However, the TensorFlow version required for this process can be an issue. The current [working solution](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/5161#issuecomment-1817762594) (at least for Google Colab) is to re-install it as follows:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.13.0rc0
```

And then run the model export. The content of the resulting `/yolov8n_web_model` folder:

```
/content/yolov8n_web_model

group1-shard1of4.bin
group1-shard2of4.bin
group1-shard3of4.bin
group1-shard4of4.bin
metadata.yaml
model.json
```